# Can't find the test module in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, dpkt

I cannot find the `test` module in my Anaconda's version of Python. Can anyone help me fix this. This module is used by the `dpkt` library that I am trying to use.

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Fix: You can checkout a copy of `pystone.py` from the [cpython github repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/pystone.py) and copy it to a `test` directory that is present in your `PYTHONPATH`. Or you would copy it to a `test` directory in your python project's root (ugly way).

Perhaps Anaconda Python does not ship with a copy of the `test` module. This is a standard part of Python 2.7. Other times, users accidentally overwrite their Python standard library's `test` module with something else. You can try to use the Python version that is shipped with OS X instead. If that fails as well, then try to see which `test` module is being loaded, and go from there.

```
import test
print test
```

Comment: The repository you linked to seems to be for Python 3.* Do you know about CPython for 2.*?

Comment: I copied the `test` module from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/) into Anaconda's Python source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alpine Linux ships a [`python2-tests` package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python2-tests&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=).

the quickest way to `fetch` it if you don't have an Alpine `lxc` container is from a [`main` repo here](https://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/) (or `apk fetch python2-tests` inside `lxc`).

the `.apk` can be uncompressed with an archiver to a `.tar.gz` & then just uncompress again.